# Couchbase 1.8.1 Installation Issue

Tags: windows, server, installation, couchbase, nosql

I installed couchbase 1.8.1 server on windows 8.1 machine. After the installation is complete I see that the service is not running. When I try to stop/start/register/unregister the service it gave me following error(Error: The handle is invalid). I tried as admin and have all the rights.

I am clueless as what could be the reason. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin> .\service_stop.bat
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>set NS_BIN=C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>set NS_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\..
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>set NS_ERTS=C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\erlang\erts-5.8.3\bin
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>"C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\erlang\erts-5.8.3\bin\erlsrv.exe" stop CouchbaseServer
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\erlang\erts-5.8.3\bin\erlsrv.exe: Failed to stop service CouchbaseServer.
Error: The handle is invalid.
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin>
```

Comment: Dare I ask why you're using Couchbase 1.8.1? It was released over 3 years ago (http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-1.8/#appendix-release-notes) and Couchbase Server is now at version 3.x

Comment: Its just the setup requirement.... I know its very old but have to setup the same.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Server 1.8.1 doesn't support Windows 8 (or 8.1) - it was [released before](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-1.8/#appendix-release-notes) Windows 8 was released! (03 July 2012 for Couchbase 1.8.1 vs. Oct 2012 for Windows 8).

I recommend you use an OS which [Couchbase 1.8.1 supports](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-1.8/#supported-platforms):

> The following operating systems are supported:
>   - RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.2 (Deprecated). Requires additional third-party libraries and packages.
>   - RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.4 (32-bit and 64-bit)
>   - Ubuntu Linux 10.04 (32-bit and 64-bit)
>   - Windows Server 2008 R2 (32-bit and 64-bit)

Alternatively upgrade to a newer version of Couchbase server - Windows 8 is listed as a supported platform (development only) for [2.2 and upwards](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#installing-and-upgrading).